# rails create windows like path in cygwin

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, cygwin

I am using ruby on rails in Cygwin to create a blog, and I also installed nodejs and npm. Here is what I got on the web browser:

Showing /home/Ellen/blog/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

```
module.js:338
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\cygwin64\home\Ellen\blog\cygpath -m #{tmpfile.path}'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

(in /home/Ellen/.gem/ruby/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)

Extracted source (around line #6):

```
<head>
<title>Blog</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
```

Rails.root: /home/Ellen/blog

I understand that it is because the program gave a windows like path to cygwin which supposed to be a unix like path, /cygdrive/c/...

Comment: How can I resolve this issue so that I would not encounter this any more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many solutions suggested in this forum and others, and finally resolved this problem by removing all coffee files in assets directories, and also removed the require turbolinks line in application.js, and the issue is gone!